# application resources after update

Tags: android, android-resources

I have a curiosity about application updates . What happens after such a process with the resources supposing that the update needs different resources than the ones the old version used ? Are they overwritten ?( like overwrite string.xml) or the old resources are deleted and replaced with the new ones ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resources are in the APK file. When you update the application, you replace the APK file. Hence, the resources get replaced *in toto*.